# Как обратиться к объекту, созданному через интерфейс?

Tags: java

у меня есть класс, в котором через интерфейс я создаю объекты.

```
public interface HouseBuilder
{
    void addBedroom (int length, int width, Repair repair);
    void addBedroom (int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType,
           Repair repair);
    void addBathroom (int length, int width, Repair repair);
    void addBathroom (int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType,
            Repair repair);
    void garage (int length, int width);
    void kitchen (int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType,
        Repair repair);
}

public class TwoBedroomHouse implements HouseFacilities {

    private HouseBuilder houseBuilder;

    public TwoBedroomHouse(HouseBuilder houseBuilder) {
        this.houseBuilder = houseBuilder;
    }

    public void constructHouse() { // метод строит дом
        houseBuilder.addBedroom(100, 100, COSMETIC);
        houseBuilder.addBedroom(120, 120, GRANITE, RENOVATION);
        houseBuilder.addBathroom(40, 50, COSMETIC);
        houseBuilder.addBathroom(40, 40, MOSAIC, RENOVATION);
        houseBuilder.kitchen(120, 80, MARBLE, DESIGNER);
        houseBuilder.garage(60, 60);
    }
```

Теперь мне нужно создать метод, который в одной из комнат будет менять ремонт, вопрос такой: как мне обратиться к одному из созданных объектов, чтобы применить его в другом методе? быть может это не совсем правильная конструкция?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код класса `HouseBuilder`.  Вероятно, он содержит какую-то коллекцию (или несколько коллекций или просто несколько объектов) условно `ArrayList Rooms;`, в которую вы добавляете комнаты с ремонтом методами `addBedroom()` `addBathroom()` и т.д. Вот в этой коллекции и ищете нужную вам комнату по какому-то признаку.

Comment: public interface HouseBuilder {

    void addBedroom(int length, int width, Repair repair);

    void addBedroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

    void addBathroom(int length, int width, Repair repair);

    void addBathroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

    void garage(int length, int width);

    void kitchen(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

}

Comment: Вот сам интерфейс.

Comment: А каким образом вы создали объект от интерфейса `private HouseBuilder houseBuilder;` ? Вы должны сделать класс, который реализует интерфейс, все его методы. И в нем как раз определить хранилище объектов (комнат).

Comment: Я только учусь, вот получилось как-то..

Comment: public class StandardHouseBuilder implements HouseBuilder {

    private House house = new House();

    @Override
    public void addBedroom(int length, int width, Repair repair) {
        Bedroom bedroom = new Bedroom(length, width, repair);
        house.setBedroom(bedroom);
    }

  ......

Comment: это мой класс, который реализует интерфейс, то есть в нем мне нужно определить хранилище объектов?

Comment: Да, как-то так. И в классе `TwoBedroomHouse` вы должны создать объект уже вашего класса, а не интерфейса.

Comment: Дмитрий! Спасибо большое! Буду переделывать!

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид принятого ответа.  P.S. - справочник, может поможет https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.7.php

Comment: Спасибо за справочник.
Теперь у меня не работает метод constructHouse()..

Answer (score 1):

Создавать объекты интерфейсов нельзя. Вы должны сделать класс, который реализует интерфейс, все его методы. И в нем как раз определить хранилище объектов (комнат).

```
public interface HouseBuilder
{
    void addBedroom (int length, int width, Repair repair);
    // и т.д.
}
class HBuilder implements HouseBuilder {
    public ArrayList<Room> Rooms;

    @Override public void addBedroom (int length, int width, Repair repair){
     // код добавления Bedroom в коллекцию Rooms
    }
}
public class TwoBedroomHouse implements HouseFacilities {

    private HBuilder houseBuilder;

    public TwoBedroomHouse(HBuilder houseBuilder) {
        this.houseBuilder = houseBuilder;
    }

    public void constructHouse() { // метод строит дом
        houseBuilder.addBedroom(100, 100, COSMETIC);
        ...
    }
```